# discord.py prevent bot from reading message as a command

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, discord.py

The bot asks the user to select a type. I have used the client.wait_for() function to get user input. The command prefix is '.' In case the user types a message starting with '.' , I do not want the bot to read it as a command and execute that command. How do I do that?
This is the code:

````
@client.command()
async def search(ctx):
    try:
        await ctx.send("Enter '"+selected_type[0]+"' or '"+selected_type[1]+"' to search for required type")
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=10, check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        selection = msg.content.title()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e: #if user does not give input in 10 sec, this exception occurs
        await ctx.send("Too slow")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Search failed.")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

```py
if not msg.content.startswith('.'): selection = msg.content.title()
```

Comment: I tried that, but the command still ends up getting executed.